# Javascript Library Quickstart

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a Javascript library that will provide some functionality for a JQuery Plugin I'm putting together.

I got the following skeleton code from searching online although I'm not quite sure how it all works (I do know it's a closure). I've added my functions via declarations.

```
(function(window, document, $) {

    function func_1(){
        return 1;
    }

    function func_2(){
        return 2;
    }

})(window, document, jQuery);
```

So I put the above code in a separate JS file and then source it in my HTML page, then I run try to run the function like so (Note: I have JQuery set up as well):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            console.log(func_1());
        });
</script>
```

However, I seem to be getting some errors in Firebug (`ReferenceError: func_1 is not defined`).

I have two questions:

1. How do I call my functions?!
2. I'd like to be able to call the functions in the following format: `className.functionName()`. How do I restructure the skeleton code to enable me do this and, say, call my function like this: `Device.func_1()`?

Thanks for your anticipated assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closure is used to hide internal functions from the rest of the code. You need to explicitly expose the public functions of the library:

```
var Device = (function(window, document, $) {
    function func_1(){
         return 1;
    }

    function func_2(){
        return 2;
    }

    var internalDevice = {
        func_1: func_1,
        func_2: func_2
    };
    return internalDevice; // expose functionality to the rest of the code
})(window, document, jQuery);
```

The `(function(window, document, $) {})(window, document, jQuery);` part is called an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE). It's used to avoid leaking all the library functions into the global scope. Otherwise, if some other library had a `func_1` function it would either be overwritten or overwrite your library's `func_1`.

The arguments to the function are used to control how the library can affect other parts of the code and relies on it. For example, someone might overwrite the window.$ library so that $ is no longer available everywhere in the code. But since you have a local reference in the closure you can still access it.

Alternatively to using the code above - returning an object - you could also assign your library directly to the global scope:

```
(function(window, document, $) {
    ...
    window.Device = internalDevice; // expose functionality to the rest of the code
})(window, document, jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer question number two, but you can create that by doing this:

```
var Device = {
function func_1()
{
// your first function
},
function func_2()
{
// your second function
}
};
```

That way you can just call:

```
Device.func_1();
```

Hop that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

When something is inside a closure the scope of it is changed to that closure. `func_1` and `func_2` can only be seen inside the anonymous function calling them and below.